# Jquery sortable index position

Tags: javascript, jquery

I try to change the index 0 by 1 at the start position in order to refresh the position in my td attribute; How can I change this?

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#sortable').sortable({
    update: function(event, ui) {
      var data = $(this).sortable("toArray", ui.item.attr("id"));
      $(this).children().each(function(index) {
        $(this).find('td.ordre').html(index + 1);
      });
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

<table id="players" name="players" class="table table-striped">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <td>N°</td>
      <td>Nom</td>
      <td>Prénom</td>
      <td>N° licence</td>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody id="sortable">
    <tr id="1" data-position="1">
      <td class="ordre">1</td>
      <td>Name 1</td>
      <td>Surname 1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="2" data-position="2">
      <td class="ordre">2</td>
      <td>Name 2</td>
      <td>Surname 2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="3" data-position="3">
      <td class="ordre">3</td>
      <td>Name 3</td>
      <td>Surname 3</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: share your html please. also explain what you are trying to achieve in a little details

Comment: hi @TowkirAhmed i updated the post

Comment: I have added a snippet based on your code, can you please provide some ( at least 3/4 rows of the output data ) ?
I think you are using some other library to populate the data with a for loop.

Comment: @TowkirAhmed i updated with some data, as you can see when i drag the element 2 to 1 i get 0. i would like to get 1

Comment: Change `.html(index)` to `.html(index+1)`

Comment: that's really strange i tried before but all my positions was set to 1 . really strange thanks a lot for your help